# Which toolbox does facebook app use

Tags: windows, xaml

[image: windows 8.1 facebook app]

which toolbox is that?

I use ListView now, but if I click it, it looks like I choose it, not click it.

so I want to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear but I'll share some information about ListView.

I don't know which facebook app is that but official Facebook App (not beta) is using ListView too AFAIK.You can customize ListView's Style and ItemTemplate to achieve that.

Theese 2 MSDN articles about ListView will help you.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709922.aspx